# How to empty div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need that when user will click on 'div_id' div will be null or empty - I do not want to hide it.
`.empty()` doesn't work -  the div just fast blinks and stays on the screen:

```
$(div_id).click(function () {
    $(div_id).empty();
});
```

This is my all code:

```
function paintOrders(items) {

    var container =
        '<table border="2">' +
    $.each(items, function () {
            div_id = '#div_' + this.SHIPMENT;
            container += '<tr>' + '<td>' + div_id + '--' + this.CUSTOMER_NAME + '</td>' + '</tr>';
    });
    container += '</table>';
    
    $(div_id).click(function () {
        $(div_id).empty();
    });
    $(div_id).append(container);
    $(div_id).html(container);
}
```

When I use `.empty` or `.html`
the div blinks. What might be the problem?

Comment: did you try `.html('')`?

Comment: Why is everyone suggesting `.html("");` as though it would give a different result?

Comment: @Kristina88: "It blinks" makes it sound like the page is reloading. Are these actually `<a>` elements you're clicking on? Also, there are a number of issues with your code, mostly with respect to your use of the `div_id` variable. Is this your actual code we're looking at?

Comment: ...in fact, `var container = '<div>' + '<table border="2">' + $.each(...` doesn't make sense to me at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.empty()` is supposed to remove the child nodes, try `.html('');` instead.

If you're adding divs dynamically, you have to use .live instead of .click:

```
$(div_id).live('click', function () {
        $(div_id).empty();
    });
```

Comment: it blinks too..seems like it is gone and comes again so fast...what might be the prob?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(div_id).click(function () {
    $(div_id).html("");
});
```

Comment: it blinks too..seems like it is gone and comes again so fast...what might be the prob?

Comment: check your each loop again and check where you on which div you put the click event. I don't see you creating a div with an id anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html() and set its value to empty

```
$(div_id).click(function () {
             $(div_id).html("");
      });
```

Comment: it blinks too..seems like it is gone and comes again so fast...what might be the prob?

Answer (score 0):

`.empty()` works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/KXRCj/

You just need to use:

```
$(div_id).click(function() {
    $(this).empty();
});
```

Comment: it blinks too..seems like it is gone and comes again so fast...what might be the prob?

Comment: I read the rest of the code which I skipped before. Honestly, I can't understand what you're trying to do by calling first `.append(container)` and then `.html(container)`. Anyway, the problem is in the code generating the table, not in your usage of `.empty()`.

Answer (score -2):

I think you're loading the div's content twice, once with "append" and another time with "html". There's no need for both.

Comment: This isn't a complete answer, but anyway, because of the order (`append` first, then `html`), it wouldn't duplicate the content inside of the `div`.